# Tracking Avaya call volume via SNMP?

Tags: monitoring, snmp, avaya

Our company uses an Avaya IPOffice system.  We're relatively light on our call volume, but I'd really like to know where our peaks and valleys are.  Is it possible to track call usage on the Avaya IPOffice unit via SNMP?

Here's what I know:

- Avaya publishes their SNMP libraries on the admin CD (and on the web - http://www.oidview.com/mibs/6889/md-6889-1.html).  I've looked through them but can't find what I want.
- Avaya does have a program called "System Status" that shows all the values I care about, but I wish I could track it through my main SNMP system.

What I would really like to know is one or more of the following:

- Of my 24 available lines, how many are in use at the moment?
- How many internal-to-internal conversations are happening at the moment?  These do not use our available external lines, but would be interesting to track.
- How many internal phones are currently off-hook?

Comment: You may want to get an Avaya DevConnect account and post there. They were able to help our devs figure out the APIs and TAPI stuff. I agree that System Status is cumbersome to use and report from. I wonder if Splunk can interact with IP Office...

Answer (score 1):

Glancing at the MIBs from the link you sent me, I'd say yes. Read your Avaya documentation on how to set up the IPOffice SNMP agent and then do that. If you're using Windows, then get the [Ireasoning MIB Browser](http://ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml). That program will allow you to do SNMP GETs to the IPO SNMP agent via IP address as well as setup a trap receiver to test your IPO traps. Point your IPO SNMP traps to the Ireasoning IP address once the Ireasoning trap receiver is up and then start doing things to the system that would induce an alarm.

If you're using a Unix-type environment, then setup a [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) daemon and couple that with something like [SNMPtt](http://snmptt.sourceforge.net/) to translate your traps. Another useful tool is the [libsmi](http://svn.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/projects/libsmi/) suite that has useful programs like `smidump -f identifiers <my_MIB_file>` which will allow you to look at your MIBs in a more human readable manner.